# Describe all 2 × 2-matrices A such that $A^TA = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Describe all $2 × 2$ matrices $A$ such that $A^TA = I$

I came up with this set of equations:

Given$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix},$$ 
$\\$
$$\begin{array}{lcl}a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2=1\\
a_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}a_{22}=0\\
a_{12}a_{11}+a_{22}a_{21}=0\\
a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2=1\\\end{array}$$

I don't know where to go next, should I involve trig?

Comment: These equations are probably fine. From these you can characterise the matrix by saying that the row vectors are orthonormal.

Comment: The problem defines $A$ implicitly by an equation. If your answer also defines it implicitly by an equation not much is gained, unless the equation is much simpler. In this case they are essentially the same. On the other hand, you can give the possible $A$ explicitly as a parametrization. Look at your first and last equation and compare it to $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$.

Comment: Trigonometric functions is not the only way to parametrize those matrices, but it is one way.

Comment: The two middle equations are the same - and will be the same when you correct it. This will say that the two column vectors are unit vectors, and that they are orthogonal.

Comment: It defines the orthogonal group.

Answer (score 2):

The first and the last equations look like $\cos^2x+\sin^2 x=1$. So let's choose $a_{11}=\cos x$, $a_{21}=\sin x$, $a_{22}=\cos y$, and $a_{12}=\sin y$. The second (or third) equation tells you that $$\cos x\sin y+\sin x\cos y=0$$ This can be simplified to $\sin(x+y)=0$. If we restrict the range of $x$ and $y$ to be from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, you get $x=-y$ 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos x & -\sin x \\
\sin x & \cos x \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
This is a rotation in 2D.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have $$A = \pmatrix{ \frac{2}{1+t^2}-1 & -\frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \\ \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} & \frac{2}{1+t^2}-1 }$$ as another solution.

Comment: @ja72 That's the same. Use $\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=\sin x$. Then $\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{(1+t^2)^2-4t^2}}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac2{1+t^2}-1$

Comment: @ja72: Note that Andrei has essentially shown that the trigonometric one is the only solution. This does not mean that the only way of **expressing** the solution is via trigonometry. Indeed, you found a way of doing it via rational functions.